# General tips for simplifying vector/matrix expressions

Tags: matrices, vectors

So I encountered some vector/matrix equalities, such as:

let $x_i$ be column vectors of matrix $X$, then $\sum_{i} x_i x_i^T = X X^T$.

I only knew how to prove this by expanding and comparing each term in the resulting matrices on both sides, but I recently learnt a new trick:
$\sum_{i} x_i x_i^T = (x_1, ... x_n)(x_1^T, ... x_n^T)^T  = X X^T$ which directly finishes the proof.

Essentially this technique is treating the sum of some products as a single vector inner product. I've never seen this technique before and thought it was very useful. Are there any other general tips for simplifying vector/matrix product expressions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if I understood it. If $x_{i}$ is a column vector, isn't $\sum_{i=1}x_{i}^{T}x_{i}$ a number?

Comment: I must have made an error. Edited and should be correct now.

Comment: There are many useful ways to interpret the product of matrices by grouping terms in different ways: as the dot products of rows of one matrix with columns of another, as linear combinations of the columns of the first matrix or rows of the second, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf

"Civilization advances by extending the number of important operations which we can perform without thinking of them." - Alfred North Whitehead